# Designing an application around HMVC and AJAX [Kohana 3.2]

Tags: ajax, kohana, hmvc

I am currently designing an application that will have a few different pages, and each page will have components that update through AJAX. The layout is similar to the new Twitter design where 'Home', 'Discover', and 'Connect' are separate pages, but interacting within the page (such as clicking 'Followers' or 'Following') uses AJAX.

Since the design requires an initial page load with several components (in the context of Twitter: tweets, followers, following), each of which can be updated individually through AJAX, I thought it'd be best to have a default controller for serving pages, and other controllers with actions that, rather than serving full pages,  strictly handle querying the database and returning JSON  objects. This way, on initial page load several HMVC requests can be made to gather the data for each component, and AJAX calls can also be made to update each component individually.

My idea is to have a Controller_Default that handles serving pages. In the context of Twitter, Controller_Default would contain:

```
action_home()
action_connect()
action_discover()
```

I would then have other Controllers that don't deal with serving full pages, but rather components of pages. For instance, in the context of Twitter Controller_Tweet may have:

```
action_get()
```

which returns a JSON object containing tweets for a specific user. Action_home() could then make several HMVC requests to get the data for the several different components of the page (i.e. make requests to 'tweet/get', 'followers/get', 'following/get'). While on the page, however, AJAX calls could be made to the function specific controllers (i.e. 'tweet/get') to update the content.

My question: is this a good design? Does it make sense to have the pages served through a default controller, with page components served (in JSON format) through other function specific controllers?

If there is any confusion regarding the question please feel free to ask for clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the strengths of the HMVC pattern is that employing this type of layered application doesn't lock you into a workflow that might be difficult to change later on.

From what you've indicated above, this would be perfectly acceptable as a way of serving content to a client; the default controller wraps sub-requests, which avoids multiple AJAX calls from the client to achieve the same goal.

Two suggestions I might make:

1. Ensure that your Twitter back-end requests are abstracted out and managed in a library to make the application DRY'er and easier to maintain.
2. Consider whether the default controller is making only the absolutely necessary calls on each request. Employ caching to avoid pulling infrequently changed data on every request (e.g., followers might only be updated every 30 seconds). This of course depends entirely on your application requirements, but if you get heavily loaded you could quickly find your Twitter API request limit being reached.

One final observation: if you do find the server is experiencing high load and Twitter API requests are taking a long time to return, consider provisioning another server and installing a copy of your application. You can then "point" sub-requests from the default gateway application to your second application server, which should help improve response times if the two servers are connected by a high-speed link.